# If barycenter true, then how general relativity explain it?

Tags: general-relativity, mass, astrophysics, orbital-motion, astronomy

I found that earth actually doesn't orbit sun. Sun and other planets both orbit the barycenter(Their central of mass).Then, what about Einstein's theory ? That heavy mass(sun) wrap space-time, thus small masses(planets)orbit around it? How barycenter can be explained in a wrapped space? how barycenter can be true in gravity and general relativity?
I tried to find an answer in Google. But i couldn't find any relation between them or how barycenter explanation work in space wrap explanation.

Comment: Welcome to SE. A word of advice: general relativity is one of the main theories known to physics, it was devised and used by some of the best scientists in the world. So you should probably consider that you didn't understand something (and it's fine, this is the place to ask) rather than assume that you saw something that Einstein didn't. So I suggest that you rephrase your question, so that it isn't closed.

Comment: No research effort, unclear formulation. Don't expect an answer under these circumstances. https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I suspect you are being confused by the awful "rubber sheet" illustrations.  General relativity is mathematically complex and that visualization is very, very misleading.  In the solar system general relativistic effects are very, very small and for many purposes you can use Newtonian physics.

Answer (score 2):

You are placing too much weight on the idea of the barycentre.

Even for Newtonian gravity, the concept of the [barycentre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter) as a fixed point around which bodies travel in elliptical orbits only strictly applies to pairs of bodies - the [two body problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-body_problem).

In the case of the solar system, we can say that each planet approximately orbits its mutual barycentre with the Sun - but only if we ignore gravitational interactions with the other planets. Note that this is only an approximation - it does not help if you want to calculate planetary orbits to a high degree of precision.

So even in Newtonian gravity, the barycentre is only a convenience that is sometimes used to simplify calculations - it is not central to the theory of gravity. In general relativity it is not a particularly useful concept at all.

Comment: The barycenter concept is extremely important when analyzing timing or Doppler observations in astronomy.  The barycenter of the total mass of the solar system moves on a trajectory that is, for practical observations, a straight line at constant velocity relative to the rest of the universe. "Barycentric correction" of observations removes the effects of the motion of the observatory within the solar system. It is not a mere convenience: it is essential for precise measurement.

Comment: @JohnDoty The Earth and the other planets only approximately orbit the solar system's barycentre. and the solar system's barycentre only approximately moves in a straight line. A good enough approximation for some purposes, but it is still only an approximation in anything other than a two-body situation.

Comment: For what purpose does the barycenter fail to move in a straight line? The straight line approximation is adequate for parts per trillion phase measurements of pulsars...

Comment: @JohnDoty The solar system is revolving around the centre of the Milky Way. The Milky Way is accelerating towards Andromeda. The Local Group of galaxies is accelerating towards the centre of the Laniakea Supercluster. These accelerations may be small enough to be ignored over periods of hours or days, but not over millions of years.

Comment: Sure, but that's not relevant to the profound difficulty that barycentric correction solves.

Comment: @JohnDoty So it is a convenient approximation that simplifies calculations in some circumstances - but it is still only an approximation, and not a fundamental part of Newtonian gravity. We are going round in circles. I am done here.

Comment: Observations are fundamental to physics. Gravity theory was constructed to match observations. Barycentric correction isn't a convenience: it is essential to getting the observations right.